# Replace string and remain the file format

Tags: linux, awk

I have a question follow by [replace entire string in one column based on matching substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52997591/bash-replace-entire-string-in-one-column-based-on-matching-substring)

I would like to replace the string in column 2 with the string in column 3, if the string in column 2 is "unidentified"

I have tried the following code

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '$2=="unidentified" {$2=$3}1'
```

Here is my input

```
OTU1019 Gibberella  Gibberella_tricincta
OTU1001 unidentified Glomeraceae_sp
```

It did the task, but it also changes the file format

Here is the output from that code:

```
OTU1019 Gibberella  Gibberella_tricincta
OTU1001 Glomeraceae_sp
    Glomeraceae_sp
```

The desired output should be:

```
OTU1019 Gibberella  Gibberella_tricincta
OTU1001 Glomeraceae_sp Glomeraceae_sp
```

How do I keep them in a same line after replacing string?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems [working well](https://ideone.com/WhnBrL).

Comment: could you please check `cat -v Input_file` once if you have control M characters there present?